# create an expand content or show more content button in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i am trying to basically add a expand button to my react app that will reveal more information and i would prefer that the app expand the div size to reveal the additional content, so the its basically an expand button, i understand i need to utilize the usestate property and a function however i am having a hard time figuring out how do i update the css of the student div to expand and reveal the added information. The added information is the grades portion (FYI).

**UPDATE:** I have found a way to display the changes the problem i am facing is to get the state to start as isExpanded false so when a user clicks the plus button it expands to reveal the class hidden information again

here is my App.js file

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState(null);
  const [filterData, setFilterData ] = useState(null);
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);

  const studentdata = 'https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students';

  function getStudents(){
    fetch(studentdata)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        setFilterData(data.students);
        setStudents(data.students);
        setIsExpanded(false);
      })
  }



  const searchByName = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    // Get the search term
    const searchItem = event.target.value.toLowerCase().trim();
    // If search term is empty fill with full students data
    if(!searchItem.trim()) {
      setFilterData(students);
    }
    // Search the name and if it found retun the same array
    const serachIn = (firstName, lastName) => {
      if(firstName.indexOf(searchItem) !== -1 || lastName.indexOf(searchItem) !== -1) {
        return true;
      }
      let fullName = firstName.toLowerCase()+" "+lastName.toLowerCase();
      if(fullName.indexOf(searchItem) !== -1) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    };
    // Filter the array 
    const filteredData = students.filter((item) => {
      return serachIn(item.firstName, item.lastName);
    });
    // Set the state with filtered data
    setFilterData(filteredData);
  }

  function exp() {
    if(isExpanded){
      setIsExpanded(true);
    }


  }

   return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Students</h1>

      <div>
        <button className="fetch-button" onClick={getStudents}>
          Get Students
        </button>
        <br />
      </div>

      <div className="search" id="search">
          <input type="text" name="serachByName" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search by name" onChange={(e) => searchByName(e)} ></input>
      </div>

      {filterData && filterData.map((student, index) => {
       var total = 0;
       for(var i = 0; i < student.grades.length; i++) {
        var grade = parseInt(student.grades[i]);
        total += grade;
       }
       const avg = total / student.grades.length;
       const average = avg.toString();
       const grade1 = student.grades[0];
       const grade2 = student.grades[1];
       const grade3 = student.grades[2];
       const grade4 = student.grades[3];
       const grade5 = student.grades[4];
       const grade6 = student.grades[5];
       const grade7 = student.grades[6];
       const grade8 = student.grades[7];

      return(
      <div className={'student' + isExpanded ? 'expanded' : '' } key={index}>
        <div className="image">
          <img src={student.pic} id="icon"></img>
        </div>

        <div className="text">
          <h3 id="name">{student.firstName} {student.lastName}</h3>
          <p id="detail"><strong>EMAIL:</strong> {student.email}</p>
          <p id="detail"><strong>COMPANY:</strong> {student.company}</p>
          <p id="detail"><strong>SKILL:</strong> {student.skill}</p>
          <p id="detail"><strong>AVERAGE:</strong>: {average}%</p>
          <p id="detail" className="hidden">
            <br></br>Test 1 :{grade1}  
            <br></br>Test 2 :{grade2}
            <br></br>Test 3 :{grade3}  
            <br></br>Test 4 :{grade4}
            <br></br>Test 5 :{grade5}  
            <br></br>Test 6 :{grade6}
            <br></br>Test 7 :{grade7}  
            <br></br>Test 8 :{grade8}
          </p>
        </div>

        <div className="expand">
          <button className="expand_btn" onClick={exp()} id="expand_btn">+</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      )}
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and my css file

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400&display=swap');

.root{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}



.App {
  text-align: center;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin-top: 75px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.student{
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.text{
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 7%;
  width: 300px;
}

.image{
  padding-left: 15%;
}

#icon{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#name{
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#detail {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

.search {
  width: 80%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#searchbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


.expand {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#expand_btn {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  font-size: 50px;
  color: lightskyblue;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.expanded{
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue in this codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-bird-j5vrm

Check and let me know if this helps.

There are many ways to solve your problem. One way is adding `isExpanded` flag to each object in the students array so that each student object would know if that is expanded or not. And I have used the flag like this

```
className={"student " + student.isExpanded ? "expanded" : " "}
```

As per your implementation, isExpanded was being set globally so every student item would be set as Expanded and there was no way to know which item was expanded.

Note: I have implemented only for getStudents and not filterStudents.